# Recover original variable name from `lm()`

Tags: r, ggplot2, lm

I'm interested in automating the plotting of models in ggplot2. Based on a [discussion](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/4552#issue-940615677) on the ggplot2 issue tracker, I believe some wrapper like the following should work.

```r
geom_predict <- function(model, fixed_terms = list(), ...) {
  force(model)
  force(fixed_terms)
  fun <- function(x) { 
    terms <- c(list(x = x), fixed_terms)
    predict(model, newdata = do.call(data.frame, terms))
  }
  geom_function(fun = fun, ...)
}
```

This works pretty well if the model is of the form `y ~ x`.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tibble)

set.seed(0)
df <- tibble(
  x = runif(20, max = 10),
  y = 5 + 2 * x + 0.5 * x^2 + rnorm(20)
)

fit <- lm(y ~ poly(x, 2), data = df)

ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_predict(fit)
```

[image]

However, it breaks down if the model is of the form `some_name ~ other_name`.

```r
# Nevermind whether the model makes sense
fit <- lm(pressure ~ poly(temperature, 2), data = pressure)

ggplot(pressure, aes(temperature, pressure)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_predict(fit)
#> Warning: Computation failed in `stat_function()`:
#> object 'temperature' not found
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-07-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

I'm not completely familiar with the structure of models in R, but I would like to extract terms from the model, as they were in the input data. The `terms()` function doesn't fit the bill because I can only extract `poly(temperature, 2)`. I think I need a way to do this:

```r
magic_function(fit)
#> [1] "temperature"
```

I could then use this to rename the terms before feeding the data to the `predict()` function. Any ideas?

Comment: My solution ignores the `fixed_terms` part. You would need to adjust for whatever you are using them for.

Comment: Yeah that's perfectly fine. I can work out from here how to go about this, now that I'm unstuck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to extract the name of the x-variable from the model:

```
geom_predict <- function(model, fixed_terms = list(), ...) {
  force(model)
  force(fixed_terms)
  vars <- all.vars(model$call$formula)
  stopifnot("Only models with one predictor possible" = length(vars) == 2L)
  xname <- vars[2]
  fun <- function(x) { 
    terms <- c(setNames(list(x), xname), fixed_terms)
    predict(model, newdata = do.call(data.frame, terms))
  }
  geom_function(fun = fun, ...)
}

fit <- lm(pressure ~ poly(temperature, 2), data = pressure)

ggplot(pressure, aes(temperature, pressure)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_predict(fit)
```

[image: resulting plot]

Comment: Thank you the `all.vars(model$call$formula)` was exactly the missing piece that I needed and couldn't come up with on my own!